# How to pass value from servlet to Dao class and perform operation and return List/ Arraylist to JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans, dao

Hello i am new at JSP developing and i need some help about JSP MVC programming I want to pass a value from Servlet and in Dao class i want to  receive it in List function and perform operation and return th array to JSP page to use ..

**Servlet**

```
String company = "ABCD";
ObsBean ComName = new ObsBean();
ComName.setCompanyName(company);
dao.getComNotify(ComName);
```

**Bean Class (ObsBean)**

```
private String CompanyName;
public String getCompanyName() {
    return CompanyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String CompanyName) {
    this.CompanyName = CompanyName;
}
```

**DAO Class (ObsDao) **

```
public List getComNotify(ObsBean ComName) {
    List<ObsBean> comNotify = new ArrayList<ObsBean>();
    String cname = ComName.getCompanyName();//getting from bean class by getter
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * from ObsNotify where notto='"+cname+"'";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            ObsBean userNotify = new ObsBean();

            userNotify.setNotifyName(rs.getString("notname"));
            userNotify.setNotifyBy(rs.getString("notby"));
            userNotify.setNotifyTo(rs.getString("notto"));
            userNotify.setNotifyDate(rs.getString("notdate"));

            comNotify.add(userNotify);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        out.print("Error for User Notification - : "+e);
    }
    return comNotify; 
}
```

**IN JSP Page :**

```
<%
ObsDao dao = new ObsDao();
List<ObsBean> ComNotify = dao.getComNotify();
for (ObsBean UserNotifi : ComNotify) {
.........
.........
}
%>
```

This is my complete code , but it shows error , why ?

**ERRORS :**

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ApexCorner.ModelDao.ObsDao.getComNotify()Ljava/util/List;

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ApexCorner.ModelDao.ObsDao.getComNotify()Ljava/util/List;
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:565)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: The answer to what? You haven't asked any question. You haven't said what the problem was with the code (other than disrespecting naming conventions and not using generics)

Comment: This is covered by countless tutorials. The JSP code needs to be able to access the bean.

Comment: Please edit your question with the code provided in that comment, any and all errors/exceptions, and include a concrete question.

Comment: I already edited my code , please watch. Thanks

Comment: And despite being asked several times, you still didn't post the error. An error comes with a message, and a stack trace, telling you what is wrong, and where. Why don't you even think it could be useful to know that. Read, and post the error and its complete stack trace.

Comment: Sorry i posted the error, but nothing specific error ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code I assume that "notto" in your table is a company name, so if your sql statement is correct i would rewrite your code as follows:

```
public List getComNotify(ObsBean Comname) {
    List<ObsBean> comNotify = new ArrayList<ObsBean>();
    String COM = Comname.getcompanyname();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * from ObsNotify where notto='"+COM+"'";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            ObsBean userNotify = new ObsBean();
            int totalRows = rs.getRow();

            userNotify.setNotifyName(rs.getString("notname"));
            userNotify.setNotifyBy(rs.getString("notby"));

            comNotify.add(userNotify);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        out.print("Error for User Notification - : "+e);
    }
    return comNotify; 
}
```

Comname is an object of the ObsBean type, you should retrieve the company name as a string before you can apply it to the sql statement, also note that java is case sensitive.

in JSP do something like

```
<%
ObsDao dao = new ObsDao();
ObsDao otherdao = new ObsDao();
otherdao.setCompanyName("My company")
List<ObsBean> ComNotify = dao.getComNotify(otherdao);
for (ObsBean UserNotifi : ComNotify) {
.........
.........
}
%>
```

Comment: I'm assuming also that you have a method in the class 'ObsBean' called getcompanyname() for that object if you don't make sure to add getters ans setters

Comment: public List getComNotify(ObsBean ComName) {
        String comname = ComName.getCompanyName();
        List comNotify = new ArrayList();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * from ObsNotify where notto=?";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, comname); 
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

I edit my code like this but this shows error also in the jsp page ..... i user getter and setter for CompanyName in Bean class....

Comment: I want to send a parameter from Servlet to Dao class and want to perform a Query avove my code and show these result in jsp page .

Comment: In your code the list has to be a list of the type of objects you are adding "ObsBean" see the changes I made. when you return your list every item in your list is an object of that type. List<ObsBean> comNotify = new ArrayList<ObsBean>();

Comment: Please watch my top code again, i edit as like your code but it still shows error in jsp page ..

Comment: Apache server complains there is no such a method because you are not providing the parameter to the method see your method definition: public List getComNotify(ObsBean ComName).  You have to pass another object of the ObsBean type to the method so it can extract the company name from it. In your current case apache is looking for a method that requires no parameters and you don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dao class, there should be getter method for CompanyName. So try following code:

`STRING COM = Comname;` ,<-- change this line to `String COM=Comname.getCompanyName();`

Comment: what are you trying say ?